# How can i make like dislike button for anonymous user using django , how can i manage this session ? Please anyone could explain it?

Tags: django

Recently i'm developing my first blog website using django , no i want add like and dislike button but anyone can give multiple like , so i want to handle that . But how ? Please explain someone.

```
ef upvote(request,post_id):
    if request.method=="POST":
        post = get_object_or_404(Post,pk=post_id)
        post.likes+=1
        post.save()
        return redirect('home')
```

```
<li>
  <form id="upvote{{ post.id }}" method="post" action="{% url 'upvote' post.id %}">
         {% csrf_token %}
     <a href="javascript:{document.getElementById('upvote{{ post.id }}').submit()}">
            <button class="border_less">
                <i class="ti-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{post.likes}}Votes
           </button>
      </a>
  <input type="hidden"/>
</form>
 </li>
```

Comment: Where is the code for like and dislike?

Comment: i don't understand that how i can apply this logic ? at the same time like and dislike.

Comment: Without seeing your code or error how can I answer. Please show what have you done so far. If you are asking how you will implement Like / Dislike from the beginning then sorry your question is too broad.

Comment: sir already updated .